# Using ColdFusion 9's ORM, how do you create a property that converts a database string into a boolean value?

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm working with a legacy database that stores a boolean column as a string, where true is "Y" and false is an empty string. How would I map a property so that it's able to convert this value to an actual boolean, but still save to the database as "Y" and empty string, for legacy purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take care of this with custom getters and setters. Just create your own `getProperty` and `setProperty` methods that will convert the value both directions. I don't know that there's any other way to programatically change the meaning of a value directly through the property mappings.

```
function setProperty(value){
    if(Arguments.Value){
        this.Property = "Y";
    }else{
        this.Property = "";
    }
}

function getProeprty(){
     return (this.Property EQ "Y");
}
```

Comment: function getProperty(){
    return (this.Property EQ "Y");
}

Comment: Nice change :). Mind if I add it to the answer?